# Unwanted trailing white-spaces comes along on copy-paste

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, whitespace, nano

I'm using Tmux & Zsh (WSL) and am very frustrated with all the white-spaces that comes with when copy content from a file while using **nano**.

```
nano .zshrc
```

[image: Copied From].

When using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> unwanted trailing white-spaces comes along in the content.

[image: Content pasted to sublime].

Is there a solution?

Comment: If I'm seeing that correctly it looks like all your data is being put onto a single line and it's just word wrapping with what appears to be vscode.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, single line with a crazy amount of white-spaces

Comment: I think the whitespace is almost irrelevant though, or at least not an accurate way to describe your problem.  Your problem is mostly that all the newlines are being stripped.

Comment: True, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found that horribly irritating too, and I disabled it with

```
unset zle_bracketed_paste
```

After that, you'll have to rely on the terminal emulator to handle all the copy-pasting.

You can read about `zle_bracketed_paste` in the `zshparam(1)` manpage.

Hopefully someone will answer you with the whole theory behind it.

Comment: Where did u place ```unset zle_bracketed_paste``` ?

Comment: In `~/.zshrc`. Your problem may be different, caused by the terminal emulator. What terminal emulator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `set indicator` (in `~/.nanorc` or `/etc/nanorc`), too bad as I liked the scrollbar quite a lot :(